# Returning XML file from Controller

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

I have an XML file I want to return from my Spring MVC Controller but all the examples I've found use JAXB by first representing the data as an object (I know it's the regular case). In my case, the XML representation is static and stored in an XML file and I simply need to return this file from the Controller.

I thought about reading the file using some XML parser and then pass the raw data to the Controller using some low-level Spring annotation but I'm sure there is a better way to do the same.

Thanks

Comment: I think your approach of reading the file and sending to client is fine, still you can post your code to check something better can be done on that.

Comment: If you just want to serve a static file of any kind consider [using resource mappings](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch12s02.html).

Comment: @Bart That's exactly my question, how to serve a static XML file from a Controller method? The file is already in the WEB-INF/resources directory which is mapped. Currently, I redirect the caller using 302 to the resource but I would like to return the resource to avoid this unnecessary round-trip.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring MVC it's possible to map static files to a path using [`mvc:resources`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/files/**" location="/static-resources" />
```

It's best to place the static files outside the WEB-INF directory since this directory is supposed to be publicly inaccessible.